# Regex for searching URLS with excluding some words

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to search and replace all URLs in the text. However, I have some words that I need to exclude from the search. For example `(?!word)(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9.]+)\.(?:[a-zA-Z]{2,3})`. This regex found all urls but not exclude urls which contain `word`. Please help me finish this regex.

I'm tried:

```
const text = `This is a sample text with links: www.example.com, https://www.hello.com, http://www.google.com, https://word.com, http://word.com
www.word.com https://www.site.frs www.word.com asasd.cds qdwdew.www asd.cdd 
sdsd https://www.word.com
https://www.word.frs some text hello word https www.example.wfd asdasd wwwsds.dsad.word.com 
`;

const regex = /(?!word)(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9.]+)\.(?:[a-zA-Z]{2,3})/gm;

const matches = text.replace(regex, '[xxx]');;

console.log(matches);
```

I got this result:

```
This is a sample text with links: [xxx], [xxx], [xxx], [xxx], [xxx]
[xxx] [xxx] [xxx] [xxx] [xxx] [xxx] 
sdsd [xxx]
[xxx] some text hello word https [xxx] asdasd [xxx]
```

I want to get this result:

```
This is a sample text with links: [xxx], https://www.hello.com, [xxx], https://word.com, http://word.com
www.word.com [xxx] www.word.com [xxx] [xxx] [xxx] 
sdsd https://www.word.com
https://www.word.frs some text hello word https [xxx] asdasd wwwsds.dsad.word.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass a callback function to [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) instead, which checks if the match contains the given word to decide whether or not to replace.

```js
const text = `This is a sample text with links: www.example.com, https://www.hello.com, http://www.google.com, https://word.com, http://word.com
www.word.com https://www.site.frs www.word.com asasd.cds qdwdew.www asd.cdd 
sdsd https://www.word.com
https://www.word.frs some text hello word https www.example.wfd asdasd wwwsds.dsad.word.com 
`;

const regex = /(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9.]+)\.(?:[a-zA-Z]{2,3})/gm;

const matches = text.replace(regex, m => m.includes('word') ? m : '[xxx]');
console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Arguably, the best way to do this is to specify a callback as replacement:

```js
const masked = text.replace(regex, $0 => $0.includes('word') ? $0 : '[xxx]');
```

...or, if you want to avoid false positives like `sword`:

```js
const masked = text.replace(regex, $0 => /\bword\b/.test($0) ? $0 : '[xxx]');
```

Try it:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

const text = `This is a sample text with links: www.example.com, https://www.hello.com, http://www.google.com, https://word.com, http://word.com
www.word.com https://www.site.frs www.word.com asasd.cds qdwdew.www asd.cdd 
sdsd https://www.word.com
https://www.word.frs some text hello word https www.example.wfd asdasd wwwsds.dsad.word.com
https://this.is.a.sword.com
`;

const regex = /(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9.]+)\.(?:[a-zA-Z]{2,3})/g;

const masked1 = text.replace(regex, $0 => $0.includes('word') ? $0 : '[xxx]');
const masked2 = text.replace(regex, $0 => /\bword\b/.test($0) ? $0 : '[xxx]');

console.log(masked1);
console.log(masked2);
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Alternatively, here's a pure regex solution:

```
(?!\S*\bword\b)\b(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9.]+)\.(?:[a-zA-Z]{2,3})
```

...in which `(?!\S*\bword\b)` ensures that the URL we are about to (try to) match will not contains `word`. `\b` is needed so as not to match half the URL.

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/CMzwty/1).

Try it:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

const text = `This is a sample text with links: www.example.com, https://www.hello.com, http://www.google.com, https://word.com, http://word.com
www.word.com https://www.site.frs www.word.com asasd.cds qdwdew.www asd.cdd 
sdsd https://www.word.com
https://www.word.frs some text hello word https www.example.wfd asdasd wwwsds.dsad.word.com
https://this.is.a.sword.com
`;

const regex = /(?!\S*\bword\b)\b(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9.]+)\.(?:[a-zA-Z]{2,3})/g;

const masked = text.replace(regex, '[xxx]');

console.log(masked);
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```